# Daily release using semantic release

Tags: semantic-release

We have semantic-release set up in our repo at work. Tech leads asking me to:

Let people merge to the main branch and it shouldn't trigger the release.

It requires to automatically creating releases at 5pm from the main branch (not triggered by commits)

And he doesn't want to have separate branches like alpha/beta he wants everything to get merged into the main branch. But the main branch only creates releases 5 pm every day!

Is there any way to achieve this? (We are using gitlab)

Comment: It’s achievable. All you need to explore is cicd process and trigger the pipeline using cron based triggers on main branch. For versioning there are strategies to detect the version numbers based on the commit messages.

Comment: @ManishRawat thanks for the reply. Good to hear it's achievable! 
Do I need to schedule creating tag and that runs release step? OR the tag still should be created by semantic-release?

Comment: That’s a good idea to let the schedule create tags and then pipeline triggers on tags.